# Is there a way to assign a shortcut key to open the Windows Task Manager?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, task-manager

I open Task Manager very often. Is there a way to assign a shortcut key to open the Windows Task Manager?

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles across this question when interested in Mac OS X, there the shortcut for the *Force Quit Applications* dialog is `Cmd-Opt-Esc`. Use `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor` for anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> will open Windows Task Manager for you.